# How can I use SendKeys at the windows 7 login window?

Tags: python, sendkeys

Ok so I'm making an arduino based physical login system for my computer. Basically I have a reed switch set up so that when it is tripped it sends some serial information to a python program and when that happens SendKeys types out the password(hopefully into the login box). I know it's not secure at all but it's more or less a proof of concept. Here is the part of the code that is sending the password.

```
while var == 1:
xx = ser.read()
print xx
if xx == '7':
    SendKeys.SendKeys(Info.passwd + """{ENTER}""")
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    pass
```

I'm not really having any trouble with the code, it works for other things like notepad but when I try to use it at the login window I get nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to extend the functionality of the Windows Vista/7/8 logon screen is to implement a Credential Provider.  There is an API for this, with a good introduction [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404303%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Pre-Vista, such customization was achieved using custom GINA DLLs.

So, you will have to alter your Python program to interface with one of those two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The windows 7 loginscreen is designed to stop this from working. You'd essentially have to plug in a usb or ps/2 device that acted as a keyboard and received commands from your script. Thinking about it bluetooth might work well too.

Whichever approach it's going to be a lot of work...

Comment: Well I might try connecting a teensy and having the data sent through there.

Comment: Thinking about it, if that doesn't work out, ps/2 was a fairly simple protocol, knocking up a fake keyboard should be easy enough...